# WPML - Pages not synced?

Tags: plugin-wpml

I have a problem with WPML and sync pages?

Well, when I want to only translate my home page from lang to lang, my page lost her state. E.g - Front Page

**The content is copied, but the page does not share the same URL but creates a new page.
Why is that case?**

Ps.

[image]
WPBakery Page Builder is used.